# Index Error: list index out of range in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.7 with Django Rest Framework. I've written an API that detects the login of a user as follows:

```
def login_check(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_anonymous():
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            'success': False
        }))
    else:
        try:
            user_obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user__pk=user.id)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            main_obj = User.objects.get(pk=user.id)
            user_obj = UserProfile(user=main_obj)
            user_obj.save()
        fb_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, provider='facebook')
        print fb_uid[0].uid
        user_obj.profile_photo_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?width=300&height=300".format(fb_uid[0].uid)
        user_obj.save()
        serialized = UserProfileSerializer(user_obj)
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I face an error with this view which shows the following traceback

```
IndexError at /loginCheck/
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/loginCheck/
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: f:\App\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __getitem__, line 178
Python Executable:  f:\App\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['f:\\App',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\DLLs',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\lib',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\lib\\plat-win',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\Scripts',
 'c:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'c:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'f:\\App\\venv',
 'f:\\App\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is an error in my code or Django's query.py. I'd appreciate help in figuring out the problem here

Comment: You might be having problem with line `print fb_uid[0].uid` when search returns empty result.

Comment: Have you checked `SocialAccount.objects.filter` actually returns a list that isn't empty? You could try `print len(fb_uid)` straight after that call. You may need more defensive code to handle when there are no results.

Comment: So I just use a try and except. If it's empty. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) method instead of `[0]` indexing of queryset:

```
so_account = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=user.id,
                                          provider='facebook').first()
if so_account:
    fb_uid = so_account.uid
    ...
```

Comment: The return type of filter function is always `django.db.models.query.QuerySet`. Isn't it possible to get one of the records like `so_account[2]` if there are more than 2 records in queryset? Then why is it not possible to use `so_account[0]` if the number of records is one.

Comment: It is possible to use `so_account[0]` if the number of records is one (or more).  But if the number of records is zero, then the `IndexError` will be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

In the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Says that:

```
Entry.objects.order_by('headline')[0]
Entry.objects.order_by('headline')[0:1].get()
```

> Note, however, that the first of these will raise IndexError while the second will raise DoesNotExist if no objects match the given criteria. See get() for more details.

So if that is possible that your query will return no data at all. You might want to use `Entry.objects.order_by('headline')[0:1].get()` instead of its shortcut `[0]`